# React Facebook Login - Hide Button after Login

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I have a simple React app that logs in with facebook and save the details to a firebase database.

What do i need to do to hide the Facebook button and display a text message saying logged in?

```
function App() {

const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    const payload = {
        id: response.id,
        name: response.name,
        email: response.email,
        token: response.accessToken,
        picture: response.picture

    }

    writeUserData(response.id, response.name, response.email)

};

function writeUserData(id, name, email) {
    fire.database().ref('usersUsername/' + name).set({
        fbID: id,
        name: name,
        refDJ: "none",
        email: email
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            // The write failed...
        } else {
            // Data saved successfully!

            // Change Button to Text Coming soon to IOS



        }
    });
}

return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <p>
        <FacebookLogin
            //autoLoad={true}
            appId="2009920755111111" //APP ID NOT CREATED YET
            fields="name,email,picture"
            callback={responseFacebook}
            textButton = "Join with Facebook"
            icon="fa-facebook"
        />
    </p>

  </header>
</div>
```

);
}

export default App ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to save the state of the App. You need the state to tell whether the user has logged in or not, and depending on that state, show a button or the text.

First, you need to declare what kind of variable you want, `loggedIn`, and the initial value, `false`:

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
```

Then, you can use the `loggedIn` state to determine what to render and update it when the user logs in.

Heres the full code:

```
function App() {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    const responseFacebook = (response) => {
        const payload = {
            id: response.id,
            name: response.name,
            email: response.email,
            token: response.accessToken,
            picture: response.picture

        }

        writeUserData(response.id, response.name, response.email)
    };

    function writeUserData(id, name, email) {
        fire.database().ref('usersUsername/' + name).set({
            fbID: id,
            name: name,
            refDJ: "none",
            email: email
        }, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                // The write failed...
            } else {
                // Data saved successfully!
                setLoggedIn(true)

                // Change Button to Text Coming soon to IOS
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            { !loggedIn ?
                <FacebookLogin
                    //autoLoad={true}
                    appId="2009920755111111" //APP ID NOT CREATED YET
                    fields="name,email,picture"
                    callback={responseFacebook}
                    textButton = "Join with Facebook"
                    icon="fa-facebook"
                />
            :
                <p>Logged In!</p>
            }
      </header>
    </div>

); }

export default App ;
```

Comment: It looks perfect but i notice it just always says logged in. https://onthesesh.ie/

Comment: Oops, I have a small typo; I'm supposed to negate the loggedIn in the return. I changed it in my answer.

Comment: This is really strange. I get a facebook error when i implement this "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can." Wheres before i definitely get a result logged to Console.

Comment: Hm interesting. Does the facebook login work without this new update?

Comment: Just noticed i modified app id when posting to Github. My fault.

Comment: Ah great. Is it working now? You can accept my answer if it does

Comment: Works perfect. Much Appreciated.